# Get Range on nested collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have method that gets data from Db with nested collection

Here is model

```
 public class FilterOptionDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FilterName { get; set; }
    

    public ICollection<OptionDto> Options { get; set; }
    
}
```

Here is method that get's data

```
 public async Task<List<FilterOptionDto>?> SetFilterOptions(SetFilterOptionsInputDto input)
{
    var useCase = await _dbContext.UseCases.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == input.UseCaseId);

    var dimensionsConfiguration =
        _analysisDimensionsProvider.AnalysisDimensionsSetting.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldNameDomain == input.Name);

    if (dimensionsConfiguration != null)
    {
        var filters = _mapper.Map<List<FilterOptionDto>>(await _dbContext.VwAnalysisUseCaseFilters.Where(x =>
                x.JobId == useCase!.JobId && x.IsUseCaseFilter == true && x.FilterType == "multiselect" &&
                x.IsAvailable && x.FieldNameDomain == input.Name)
            .ToListAsync());


        foreach (FilterOptionDto item in filters)
        {
            item.Options = await GetOptions(useCase?.JobId, dimensionsConfiguration.Source,
                dimensionsConfiguration.FieldNameDomain);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.SearchInput))
        {
            filters = filters.Where(x => x.Options.Any(x => x.Value.Contains(input.SearchInput))).ToList();
        }

        // filters = filters.Where(x => x.FilterName.Contains(input.Name)).ToList()
        //     .GetRange(input.Offset, input.Offset + 3);
        
        
        return filters;
    }


    return null;
}
```

on this line I need to get range on nested collection `Options` from model, how I can do this?

```
// filters = filters.********
            //     .GetRange(input.Offset, input.Offset + 3);
```

Comment: Do you want to apply this `GetRange` for all of your filters?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `Select`, `Skip`, and `Take`.

```
filters.Select(x => x.Options.Skip(input.Offset).Take(3));
```

Comment: But will return me just options, I need to return whole filters object

Now with your code it returns just `OptionsDto` instead of `FiltersOptionDto`

Comment: If you want to keep the original object as well then you could do something like `filters.Select(x => { x.Options = x.Options.Skip(input.Offset).Take(3); return x; } );`

Comment: Or `filters.ForEach(x => { x.Options = x.Options.Skip(input.Offset).Take(3); })`;